# Adding classes and other things to html elements you append?

Tags: javascript, html, append

Right now my code is:

```
        var carDiv = $("<div/>").appendTo("#content");
        var eUl = $("<ul/>").appendTo(carDiv);
```

How do I make it into 
`<ul data-role="listview"> content </ul>`

Instead of 
`<ul> content </ul>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty straightforward:

```
var eUl = $("<ul/>").attr('data-role', 'listview').appendTo(carDiv);
```